# Converting binary number to decimal number using list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have tried this code multiple times. But I'm always getting the output as 45, which is wrong.

```
a = [1, 0, 1, 1]
value = 0
a.reverse()
print(a)             #reversed list
for i in a:
    if i==1:
        for x in range(0,len(a)):
            value += pow(2,x)
    else:
        continue
print("decimal value of binary number is:",value)
```

Comment: value = sum([i * ((x + 1) ** 2) for x, i in enumerate(a[::-1])])

Comment: Do you know the `bin` function?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into bitwise operations. It'll make this more efficient and is best practice when dealing with bits. There's also more Pythonic ways to achieve this (using `int(x, 2)` for example.) With bitwise operations it would look like this:

```
for i in a:
    value |= i
    value <<= 1
value >>= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you detect a 1, you add 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 = 15, and you do this 3 times which is why you get 45. You should be doing this :

```
a=[1,0,1,1]
value=0
a.reverse()
print(a)             #reversed list
for pos, i in enumerate(a):
    if i==1:
        value += 2**pos
    else:
        continue
print("decimal value of binary number is:",value)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will convert you the list to a decimal number.

```
a=[1,0,1,1]
value=0
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    value += pow(2, i) * v

print("decimal value of binary number is:",value)
```

Output

```
decimal value of binary number is: 13
```

Answer (score 0):

When converting the list to a string, one can use the `int` function:

```
int("".join(map(str,a[::-1])), base=2)
```